# javascript is not working after traversing pages in ie11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I have a `href` tag to traverse from one page to another but after traversing from one page to another in IE11, the javascript of that page is not working. The page source is also showing previous page code.

Comment: Please add relevant html en javascript, so we can help

Comment: Define "traverse" what do you mean. Are you loading your content with Ajax?